# Are there any pre-generated numeric series with known statistical properties?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I'm trying to test a program that claims to calculate some statistical properties of a numeric sequences (like mean, median, standard deviation etc). Simple and short sequences pass the test well, but I'd like to challenge the program with either long sequences, or sequences with large and small values (to test overflows/underflows) etc. So, are there any software or online resource or other source of different numeric sequences with known statistical properties?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The US National Institute of Standards and Technology has a set of [Statistical Reference Datasets](http://www.nist.gov/itl/sed/gsg/strd.cfm) "that provides reference datasets with certified values for a variety of statistical methods", including a set labelled ['univariate summary statistics'](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/strd/univ/homepage.html) with certified values for the mean, standard deviation and lag-1 autocorrelation.

It doesn't appear to include values of the median, but accurate computation of the median shouldn't be a problem. [*Efficient* computation of the sample median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Efficient_computation_of_the_sample_median) is a little harder.

Comment: Those datasets seem to be rather short - several thousands of values at most. Are there long sequences, and sequences with some extreme values to test for overflows and precision loss? Also, are there statistical properties of the "higher order" available for these sets, like skewness, kurtosis etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You could take your favorite statistics toolbox (mine is R) and use that to start generating long timeseries of data. In R for example it is possible to generate data from all kinds of distributions. In this way you can validate that this program you are testing is in line with your other stats program. That only compares the performance to e.g. R, but I'd trust R in this regard :).

Comment: I'm looking for not just sequences, but for sequences with possible pitfalls. The distribution kind is not very much  relevant here.